# Constructive proof that every Cauchy sequence of reals converge

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Is there a proof that each Cauchy sequence converges in more constructive flavor, without using Bolzano-Weistrass? Is this valid?

For each $k$ there exist $h_k$
$$|x_n-x_m|<2^{-k},   \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space   n,m>h_k$$

Then for $n,m>h_k$
$$x_m-2^{-k}\leq x_n\leq x_m+2^{-k}$$

so that for all $n \geq h_k$
$$\text{inf}_m \{x_m-2^{-k}:m\geq h_k \} \leq x_n\leq \text{sup}_m \{x_m+2^{-k}:m\geq h_k \}$$

Now define $r'=\text{sup}_k \text{inf}_m \{x_m-2^{-k}:m\geq h_k \} $, and $r= \text{inf}_k \text{sup}_m\{x_m+2^{-k}:m\geq h_k \}$. Note that since Cauchy sequences are bounded the definitions give valid real numbers.

Now we note that $r=r'$ as
$$|r-r'|\leq 2^{-k+1} \rightarrow 0$$

And therefore $|x_k-r|\leq 2^{-k+1}\rightarrow 0$, which proves the theorem.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof that every Cauchy sequence **of real numbers** converges?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Indeed... But constructively (however, with the usual completeness axiom).

Comment: Then yes, your proof is correct.